# A SQL SYNTAX Error

Tags: sql, eclipse, derby

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
  ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PHONENUMBER VARCHAR(255), 
  ZIPCODE VARCHAR(255),  
  STATE VARCHAR(255), 
  USERNAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  STREETNAME VARCHAR(2000), 
  PASSWORD VARCHAR(255), 
  CITY VARCHAR(255), 
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

I am running a dynamic web project in Eclipse and am trying to connect my project to the database DERBY using JPA. However, it says there are some syntax problem with this statement. How could that happen?

Comment: What error message? Reported where? What RDBMS?

Answer (score 2):

`USER` is a reserved word.  Enclose it in square braces if you insist on using it.  Ideally you should just rename your table.

```
CREATE TABLE [USER] (
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PHONENUMBER VARCHAR(255),
    ZIPCODE VARCHAR(255),
    STATE VARCHAR(255),
    USERNAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    STREETNAME VARCHAR(2000),
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(255),
    CITY VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

Comment: **NO**  Don't name a table (or anything else) after a reserved word, it ends up being confusing.